# Consistency tower of ordinals and base theories up to PA?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I have looked through a bunch of resources, but I can't find a comprehensive account which would answer my question(s).

I understand PA is consistent assuming that Primitive Recursive Arithmetic is consistent and that the ordinal $\epsilon_0$ exists.
But here's where things get confusing, I can't seem to find a coherent account from this point downwards. Wikipedia seems to list the proof-theoretic ordinal of PRA [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) as $\omega^\omega$, but I can't seem to find what is the underlying theory for the consistency proof of PRA, similarly to the way PRA acts as base for PA. Moreover nowhere do I seem to find a statement if such a tower of ordinals and base theories is finite or infinite. I would assume it's finite from the way the Gentzen's consistency proof is normally presented, as being relatively finitistic. How does this tower look like, where's the bottom of the ordinal analysis leading to Gentzen's consistency proof?

Another related point is that some articles seem to imply that proof-theoretic ordinals don't make much sense for Robinson's Q. Is there a weakest undecidable theory for which ordinal analysis starts making sense?

Comment: Do you mean is the Axiom of choice consistent relative to ZF ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't mention AC at all.  I am confused about what leads to the consistency of ZF. I seem to remember some mentions of PA, but I can't find it right now and I don't remember ever seeing the ordinal required for such step. And then I am confused about what sequence of ordinals and theories leads to the consistency of PA. I understand the step from PRA + $\epsilon_0$ to PA though, but not beneath that.

Comment: What do you mean by Zermelo's set theory ?

Comment: Here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory, ZF without replacement and regularity.

Comment: Ok, its not common usage as far as I know, and Zermelo assumed choice. So basically you are asking is replacement consistent relative to the other axioms. As regularity is easy, just build the $V$ hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, basically that for the first part of question, plus the base theory and ordinal (if necessary) required for the step from arithmetic, I seem to vaguely remember some mentions of PA, but I get confused by not being able to find a coherent account.

Comment: Well I think that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of ZF-replacement. So ZF proves the consistency of ZF-replacement. and thus ZF-replacement cannot prove ZF consistent by Godel"s second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Still, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis lists only CZF and doesn't seem to provide ordinal for ZF or Zermelo set theory. I would expect that adding LEM won't change this, but I am not certain, also that page doesn't seem to list what theories are the ordinals added to, similar to the way of PRA+$\epsilon_0$ for PA

Comment: @user519216 read the last paragraph under "theories with larger proof theoretic ordinals"

Comment: The proof-theoretic ordinal of ZF is [unknown](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144041/proof-theoretic-ordinal-of-zfc-or-consistent-zfc-extensions).

Comment: Ouch, will edit my question to leave only part 2 then.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What is the "tower" you mention? (Also, my understanding is that the base theory for ordinal analysis is PRA unless mentioned otherwise. Note that it *does* make sense to analyze PRA relative to PRA, since of course PRA doesn't prove its own consistency.)

Comment: By the way, one proof theorist told me the proof theoretic ordinal of ZF was the "holy grail".